# Prevent carrierwave prepending `/uploads/`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Maybe I've got the wrong end of the stick here, but carrier wave appears to have an infuriating feature where it prepends `/uploads/` to the attribute an uploader is mounted to:

Observe:

```
<%= debug attachment %>

--- !ruby/object:PostAttachment
attributes:
  id: 27
  post_id: 75
  avatar: xoCXDRSa911peGZ4lFJ7cQ==.gif
  created_at: 2014-04-01 02:38:03.197465000 Z
  updated_at: 2014-04-01 02:38:03.197465000 Z
```

The avatar is what I want to access, and yet when I do this:

```
<%= attachment.avatar %>
```

I get this:

```
 /uploads/xoCXDRSa911peGZ4lFJ7cQ%3D%3D.gif
```

Argh! Obviously I could `gsub!` that /uploads/ away but is there a configuration i can set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
>   def store_dir
>     'public/my/upload/directory'
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> This works for the file storage as well as Amazon
>   S3 and Rackspace Cloud Files. Define store_dir as nil 
>   if you'd like to store files at the root level.

From the [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) Github page